# How to detect Hotswap

Tags: java, hotswap

Is there any way to detect when classes have changed during run-time with Hotswap?

I have a class that generates data, which I store for later use. I can trigger the data regeneration manually after Hotswap has occurred, but I would like to automate this. I'm looking for any solution that would allow me to detect when any of the classes have changed so that the data could be regenerated on the fly automatically. I would also like to detect which classes were changed, since I have multiple classes generating different data and it's overhead to regenerate all of them.

Comment: Did you try to check if a class hashCode changed? E.g. monitor if hotswap affects SomeClass.class.hashCode().

Comment: The hashCode of the class doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use java agents to monitor any changes in byte code:

API doc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html

Example:

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=589

Comment: Do I need to create a JAR for the agent or is there a simpler way to register it on-the-fly?

Comment: You need to launch JVM with the corresponding parameter: <<When you launch your application with the -javaagent:<path-to-your-JAR-file> command line argument, the JVM will open this JAR file, look for the MANIFEST.MF file, and then invoke the Premain-Class's premain() method.>>. I.e. you cannot register an agent on the fly.

Comment: It works, thank you. Is there a way make the agent directly communicate with my application or should I use sockets or something similar?

Comment: Basically, the agent must be inside the JVM you want to monitor hot-swaps. But it can communicate to other JVMs via sockets etc. - if you want to send notifications outside the JVM.

Comment: Apparently I can directly call static methods of my application from the Agent. This solution is exactly what I was looking for.